# logic if...else in htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect when **ozill.*$** to LogIn.php and to index.php for others.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ozill.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ LogIn.php?route=$1&vivo=%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} [L,QSA]
```

Like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ozill.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ LogIn.php?route=$1&vivo=%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1&vivo=%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} [L]
```

How to make the code better?

Comment: Why, what's wrong with it? Does it not work?

Comment: He's working. Just wanted to find out an alternative.

I just used a primitive example .. If there is a search for many rows and then this technique is not suitable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way you put if/else conditions in mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ozill [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ LogIn.php?route=$1&vivo=%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !ozill [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1&vivo=%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} [L,QSA]
```

i.e. negating the condition with `!` in front of matching pattern in the second rule.